# Converting a row from Eigen::Matrix to float array

Tags: c++11, eigen

I have a variable of type `Eigen::Matrix<float, 2, 3> &state` and I would like to take the first row and convert it to a `float *array_state`.

The matrix is

```
  2.59586   2.49855        37
 -1.38773 -0.816717       1.5
```

And when I run

```
printf("state position x, y, z: %f, %f, %f\n\n", array_state[0], array_state[1], array_state[2]);
```

I would expect the output to be `2.59586, 2.49855, 37`. However, the output I get is `2.59586, -1.38773, 2.49855`, which means that is looking at values also in the second row.

My implementation is as follows.

```
float *array_state = state.row(0).data();
printf("state position flatten x, y, z: %f, %f, %f\n\n", array_state[0], array_state[1], array_state[2]);
```

Where `state` is of type `Eigen::Matrix<float, 2, 3> &state`.

I am using Eigen version 3.3 and c++11.

Comment: Eigen matrices are column-major by default, not row major. That means values from a single row are not consecutive in memory. The offset between elements in the same row is not 1 (```array_state[0], array_state[1], array_state[2]```) but ```matrix.outerStride()```: ```array_state[0], array_state[1 * state.outerStride()], array_state[2 * state.outerStride()]```

Comment: Ok I see, I tought that by specifying the row it would return the raw data of the row only, and then I could iterate on that. It would make sense since I am specifying the row I am interested in with `state.row(0).data()`. But ok like that it works.

Comment: If you want a copy of the data in consecutive memory, you have to assign the row to a new vector. ```Vector3f row = state.row(0)```

Comment: Yes indeed if you do that it works, but I hoped that I could convert to raw array data in one line :/

Answer (score 0):

Can you convert the matrix to a row-major one, or just store it as row-major?

```
Eigen::Matrix<float, 2, 3, Eigen::RowMajor> state_rm = state;
float *array_state = state_rm.row(0).data();
```